# How to inspect and extract XAML style from WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I want to extract XAML styles from WPF application specially resource dictionary like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
....
```

Comment: OP, I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Is it your application? Do you have the source code?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is, but if you're trying to import a namespace, you do this: `xlmns:someName="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"`. If the namespace is in a different assembly, add `;assembly=AssemblyName` to the end of it.

Comment: @cheedep I don't have the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Styles Explorer](http://stylesexplorer.codeplex.com/), [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) with BAML viewer or even [SnoopWPF](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).