# Consuming resources defined in WPF default themes

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am writing a WPF custom control library and am implementing themes consistent with the WPF default themes i.e. in the Themes folder in my WPF custom control library project I have a resource dictionary named Aero.NormalColor.xaml which will be used when Aero.NormalColor is the desktop theme.

The default Aero.NormalColor theme defines many resources which I would like to consume in my resource dictionary (they can be downloaded from here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=158252).

e.g. it defines the following resource:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

In my Aero.NormalColor.xaml resource dictionary I am trying to consume this resource as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero, 
        Version=4.0.0.0, 
        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35;
        component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type myControls:MyControl}" TargetType="{x:Type myControls:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    ....
```

I appreciate that these resources are probably subject to change and thus consuming them is probably not recommended, however I would still like to know if this is possible, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys found in the decompiled BAML (you can view the decompiled BAML with any of the tools suggested here [How to inspect and extract XAML style from WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701432/how-to-inspect-and-extract-xaml-style-from-wpf-application)) do not correspond to the keys in the XAML files I was downloading via the link in the question and this is the reason this was not working.

The keys found in the decompiled BAML look like they have been obfuscated. When using the obfuscated keys, the resources can be consumed however, the obfuscation of these keys is another argument against doing this in the first place.